# Frozen heat pump for 1st time

Tags: central-heating

Yesterday I changed the blower motor capacitor on our heat pump and some general cleaning. Heat  Worked “great” through the night. This morning coils covered with ice. Q.Could it be wrong Capacitor; or could I have wired it backwards and that cause the freezing? Older Whirlpool system. Any help appreciated:)[image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located? Where are the "frozen coils"? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Location: OIB in South East NC. Coils are the visible coils on the heat pump. Only picture I had when question sent was of old Capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not properly wire the cap (start/ run) your motor may not be spinning at the correct speed if it spins up. 
Frozen coils are more often when the defrost is not properly cycling. 
Depending on the brand it could be time based, but more often is pressure based (with Refridgerants temps = pressure)  you could have caught it just prior to when it was going to start a defrost cycle. 
The reversing valve could also not be functioning correctly. 
More info on why you changed the cap may give us the information needed to help you.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I’ll open and double check connections ASAP . Cap was changed due to fan motor slow to start as heat pump came on. Cap change fixed same issue a 10 years ago. Seems to have fixed except for coils  icing up. Unit is 33 years old:). Was trying to nurse it through 1 more winter. Would wrong capacitor size cause icing as the Number on old one was difficult to read.

Comment: Yes the wrong phase angle won’t provide the correct speed. The cap shifts the AC phase angle that one has 2 sizes one for starting and then another size for running, if the speed is two slow the coils will ice up. I would not give up on the system if it is still running with a few small parts like contactors and caps. They really did make the compressors better back then, well the higher pressure gasses for today’s blends won’t last as long but can be 2-3x the seer rating so they don’t cost as much to run. But the R12 or possibly R22 is horribly expensive if a recharge is needed.

Comment: Thanks again Ed. Another question: if you can see pics of the old cap I sent you’ll see the wires are both the same color. Can I trace to certain spot or indicator to see which wee should connect to start or run? You are appreciated.